# Where to ask mobile communication questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Actually I want to ask questions about interfaces required for communication between network entities in mobile communication.

Comment: If you can narrow down and specify what it is you're looking for, we could help narrow down which SE site may be appropriate.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your response. I had asked this question http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25198/what-are-interfaces-in-mobile-network

Comment: Yes...I read that question before I posted that comment.  It's very unclear what it is you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to ask questions like *which one to use?* , *which one is better*? or *how do I use*?, then I suggest googling over asking this on any SE site.

If you have a *specific problem with one of the interfaces*, then you are welcome to ask it on SO or choose a more appropriate site in [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I had asked the question in Networkengineering but there is no single views. 
http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25198/actual-meaning-of-interface-in-mobile-network
can I ask this question on stackoverflow?

Comment: @dheeraj92- This will probably be closed as *too broad*. Honestly, you can google this.

Comment: @dheeraj92:  No.  It's pretty unclear what you're asking, even on Networking.SE.